# What is the best way to do the original query when you have made your own index table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Lets say that I have a table where videos are stored like this:

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
    video_id UUID,
    created_date TIMESTAMP,
    description TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    user_id UUID,
    tags LIST<TEXT>
    PRIMARY KEY(video_id)
);
```

And I want to be able to get videos tagged with "funny" tag. But I want to limit each result to 20, and paginate from there.

So I make a tag_index table

```
CREATE TABLE tag_index (
    tag TEXT,
    video_id UUID
    PRIMARY KEY (tag, video_id)
);
```

Every time I insert a new video with 3 tags, I do 4 inserts, 1 for the video, 3 for the tags. And each time a video is tagged I insert a new tag in the tag_index table.

But how do I do the queries?

Would I first do a query in the tag_index table and get 20 results of video_id, and then do another query for videos table and do an IN clause with all the video_id that I got from the first query? Or would I do 20 single select queries on the video table? That does not seem very efficient to me, or am I wrong?

How would I do this in the best way? I don't understand how I can used this self made index table in a good way that is best practice for Cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi table is the correct approach.

Now your secondary query `Select * FROM videos WHERE video_id in (1,2,3...);` this is also okay in the cassandra world but i would avoid it.

Whats going to happen is you will query a coordinator node, this node will then figure out which nodes own the 20 videos, run a query against each of them(maybe a read repair in there, some extra queries if you ran quorum etc) and then assemble and return them to you.  This is alot of network traffic.

Cassandra is not great on reads, writes are cheap, it compresses data.
Instead I would move all the video data into the tag table and duplicate it in the video table to reduce the lookups.

```
CREATE TABLE video_with_tags (
    tag TEXT,
    video_id UUID,
    created_date TIMESTAMP,
    description TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    user_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag, video_id)
);
```

Now your query looks like `Select * from videos_with_tags WHERE tag = 'x';`  The data is on one node, and it will be faster.

You'll still maintain the videos table so if you need to do maintenance (CRUD on videos and tags) you can find the rest of your tag data etc.

Remember cassandra is not an RDBMS, joins aret a thing, 3NF isn't a thing.  Writing to multiple tables on an update is okay.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1 :**

When you execute large in query this means you’re waiting on this single coordinator node to give you a response, it’s keeping all those queries and their responses in the heap, and if one of those queries fails, or the coordinator fails, you have to retry the whole thing

So Instead of using a single IN query, use separate query for each `video_id` with execute async to get the `video_id`'s details.

Example :

```
//Prepared only once
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id = ?");

//List<UUID> videoIDs;// You already have the video ids

List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (UUID videoID : videoIDs) {
    ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(statement.bind(videoID));
    futures.add(resultSetFuture);
}

for (ResultSetFuture future : futures){
     ResultSet rows = future.getUninterruptibly();
     Row row = rows.one();
     //Now you have the video details in the row     
}
```

> [Cassandra Query Patterns: Not using the “in” query for multiple partitions.](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/)

Note : *Huge number of execute async can lead to timeout exception*

**Approach #2 :**

Denormalize your schema as @Highstead Suggested

Note : *If you denormalized your table, you have to maintain consistency between them. Whenever any update occurred i.e If a video title updated then you have to update all the copies you have made when denormalization*

Comment: Though typically the first approach would be better in this case due to the schema layout it would likely end up being worse.  As the videos schema is only 1 row per partition we're going to amplify network traffic using the multi-request pattern.  You could mitigate the costs if you had a token aware driver however.


Worst case with in clause: `1+(20 * RF).`


Worst case Multi-Request: `20 * (1 + 1 * RF)`

Comment: If the driver is not using token ware policy then what happen on the denormalization model ? All 20 videos details will go through network to the coordinator node then to client. It is very imposible with async query to all 20 request goes to node other than coordinator node

Comment: Another thing in the denormalization model, when a new tag is added you have to select the full details of the video and insert again on the index table.

Comment: Token aware driver just ensures that your first request will go to a node that has your data.  So multi request becomes `20 * RF` and Denormalization would also be `20 * RF`.  The biggest advantage to the multi-request pattern is getting your data off the nodes quickly and being able to aggregate/act on queries more quickly while reducing Memory pressure on the coordinator.